# How to properly use run_detached() and stop() in pystray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pystray

I'm trying to use pystray without blocking the main thread. Based on the pystray docs we can use the function `run_detached()` to start without blocking.

I'm using pystray on windows so, apparently I don't need to pass any argument to `run_detached()` to work.

The first thing I tried is to run this code:

```
import pystray
from pystray import MenuItem as item
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def show_window(icon):
    print('Test')


def quit_window(icon):
    icon.stop()
    

icon = 'icon.ico'
image=Image.open(icon)

menu=pystray.Menu(item('Show', show_window, default=True), item('Quit', quit_window))
icon=pystray.Icon("name", image, "My System Tray Icon", menu)
icon.run_detached()
```

But I received this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "...\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 384, in <lambda>
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.run(setup)).start()
NameError: name 'setup' is not defined
```

So I tried to bypass this error by changing the line 384 in _base.py removing the setup variable

```
#threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.run(setup)).start() 
threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.run()).start()
```

The code worked like expected and created the tray icon with the menu buttons working properly.

The problem is when I press "Quit" because the `stop()` function is not working like when I use `icon.run()`.
The thread appears to keep running and the tray icon stay frozen and the program don't end.

Is there another way to make this work properly?

EDIT:
I found this issue in the official git repository [LINK](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/102) and it appears to be a bug already reported. I want to know if is possible to make a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the stop() function further to exit from the thread using os._exit will work if you don't need the calling thread to remain available.

Comment: Yes, that is a workaround for this case, but what if you *do* need to work with the calling thread afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/94 I found changing

```
threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.run()).start()
```

into

```
threading.Thread(deamon=true,target=lambda: self.run()).start()
```

works for me. My icon.stop() actually closes the thread now